# WKWebView completionHandler called before dismissal

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I am using WKUIDelegate this function to handle javascript alert

```
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Test Alert", nil)
                                                     message:message
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                           otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] autorelease];

    [alert show];
    completionHandler();
}
```

According to Apple documentation we should call compeletionHandler() of an alert after OK button is pressed on alert as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKUIDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WKUIDelegate/webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:completionHandler:)

How to call completionHandler()  after press OK button is pressed? If I don't call completionHandler() expection is thrown

```
**[WKWebViewController webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:
    completionHandler:]:
***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
   reason: 'Completion handler passed to -[WKWebViewController
   webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:
   initiatedByFrame:completionHandler:] was not called'****
```

**UPDATE:**

The solution mentioned below by Stefan is working fine with JS Alert but not with JS Confirm. Following is the code I get same exception even if the completionHandler() is called in ok and cancel button.

```
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler
{
    MKCLOG_DEBUG(@"%@", frame.request.URL);
    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:
                                NSLocalizedString(@"Test", nil) message: message
                                                            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"")
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   {
                                       MKCLOG_DEBUG(@"Cancel action");
                                       completionHandler(NO);
                                   }];

    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   MKCLOG_DEBUG(@"OK action");
                                   completionHandler(YES);
                               }];

    [alert addAction:cancelAction];
    [alert addAction:okAction];
}
```

Comment: You don't call presentViewController in the JS Confirm method. Add this line to fix 
`[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way your code is setup now, you display the `UIAlertView` and *immediately* run the `completionHandler()`. Both happen at the same time.

What you should do instead is something like this:

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:
    NSLocalizedString(@"Test Alert", nil) message: message
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"OK"
    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
      completionHandler();
}]; 
[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This will present the alert and call the `completionHandler` when the user dismisses it.

Note that I am using the `UIAlertController`, which is only available on iOS 8 and up, but that should be fine since you depend on `WKWebView`.

Comment: thanks for you reply the above code is working for JS Alert handling but not with JS Confirm. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Just add another UIAlertAction for the cancel button. Same as above but with different title and the right call to the completion handler. Post code if you need help.

Comment: It is rather obvious. You don't call presentViewController.